# Set of points plot: Graphics coloring

Tags: plotting, graphics

I have set of points which will give me three different curves. But I will be plotting them using `Graphics`.

However, I couldn't seem to understand, how to color them. Three different curves, will need three different colors.

My data points are [DataToPlot](https://pastebin.com/kZsknni6)

Here is the program:

```
Graphics[{Point[{#1, #2}]} & @@@ DataToPlot  ]
```

I will be giving the data points and plotting them using `Graphics`. This is the result of plot.
[image]

I would like different color for each of the curve.
 I was able to plot it but couldn't seem to find the way to color them. Can it be done?

Comment: Use something like   Drop[DataToPlot, {1, Length@DataToPlot, 3}]

Comment: @Jenny_mathy I couldn't get. `Drop`? for plot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a first look we can see that we can sort points in triples by `y` value:

```
Graphics @ Riffle[
    {Red, Green, Blue}
,   Point /@ Transpose[SortBy[Last] /@ Partition[DataToPlot, 3]]
]
```

[image]